# Pass JSON Object with REST

Tags: json, angular, rest, angular-cli, webstorm

I have a rest-api-service with the following call to a REST method that returns a very complex JSON object in the body of its response.  This code is from the rest-api-service.ts file.

```js
getLocalObjectsFromREST(): Observable<LocalObjects> {
        return this.http.get<LocalObjects>(this.apiURL + '/api/GetLocalObjects')
          .pipe(
            retry(1),
            catchError(this.handleError)
          )
      }

handleError(error: { error: { message: string; }; status: any; message: any; }) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Get client-side error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Get server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

I am attempting to grab that response in a component with the following that is in my app.component.ts file:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  _restApi: RestApiService | undefined;
  _localObjects: LocalObjects | undefined;

  contructor(restApi: RestApiService) {
    this._restApi = restApi;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocalObjectsFromService();
    console.log("Main object has a name of: " + this._localObjects?.mainObject.objName)
    console.log("Data Returned is " + this._localObjects);
  }

  getLocalObjectsFromService() {
    return this._restApi?.getLocalObjectsFromREST().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this._localObjects = <LocalObjects> data;
    })
  }
}
```

I am receiving no errors and yet the console logs are showing undefined return values.

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocalObjectsFromREST();
    console.log("Main object has a name of: " + this._localObjects?.mainObject.objName)
    console.log("Data Returned is " + this._localObjects);
  }

  getLocalObjectsFromService() {
    return this._restApi?.getLocalObjectsFromREST().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this._localObjects = <LocalObjects> data;
    })
  }
```

In your `ngOnInit()` you are not calling your `getLocalObjectsFromService()` function and as you are not adding a `subscribe()` after `getLocalObjectsFromREST` you are not seeing any data...

Comment: Sorry - I was runni8ng a debug so I mixed up my function calls - it is now corrected.  As for the subscribe call, it is is the getLocalObjectsFromService() and that is the call that does not work.